# Where should Network calls be made in Android

Tags: android

In which situation is it acceptable to make network calls on the UI thread? Or we can say that Network calls should never be on the main UI thread.

Comment: Network operations should never be done on main thread, if you try to do it NetworkOnMainThreadException will be thrown.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from [Android documentation:](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

> **Perform Network Operations on a Separate Thread**
>   To avoid creating an unresponsive UI, don't perform network operations on the UI thread. By default, Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher requires you to perform network operations on a thread other than the main UI thread; if you don't, a NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown.

It is never acceptable to make network calls on the UI thread.